# Compare two xml and print the difference using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml, compare

I am comparing two xml and I have to print the difference. How can I achieve this using LINQ. 
I know I can use XML diff patch by Microsoft but I prefer to use LINQ . If you have any other idea I will implement that

//First Xml

```
<Books>
 <book>  
  <id="20504" image="C01" name="C# in Depth">
 </book>  
 <book> 
  <id="20505" image="C02" name="ASP.NET">
 </book> 
 <book> 
  <id="20506" image="C03" name="LINQ in Action ">
 </book> 
 <book> 
  <id="20507" image="C04" name="Architecting Applications">
 </book> 
</Books>
```

//Second Xml

```
<Books>
  <book> 
    <id="20504" image="C011" name="C# in Depth">
  </book>
  <book> 
    <id="20505" image="C02" name="ASP.NET 2.0">
  </book>
  <book> 
    <id="20506" image="C03" name="LINQ in Action ">
  </book>
  <book> 
    <id="20508" image="C04" name="Architecting Applications">
  </book>
</Books>
```

I want to compare this two xml and print result like this.

```
Issued       Issue Type             IssueInFirst    IssueInSecond

1            image is different      C01              C011
2            name  is different      ASP.NET          ASP.NET 2.0
3            id  is different        20507            20508
```

Comment: How complex is the xml? If it is *just* root/record/@attrib it is probably doable.

Comment: Hi Marc this is very simple example  in actuall xml its little bit complex.

Comment: is difference only in values and/or attributes or can structure be different too?

Comment: Difference only in attributes values (as you see in question) . structure never change.

Comment: So whenever at least one attribute is the same in two rows it should report other two attributes as different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
//sanitised xmls:
string s1 = @"<Books>
                 <book id='20504' image='C01' name='C# in Depth'/>
                 <book id='20505' image='C02' name='ASP.NET'/>
                 <book id='20506' image='C03' name='LINQ in Action '/>
                 <book id='20507' image='C04' name='Architecting Applications'/>
                </Books>";
string s2 = @"<Books>
                  <book id='20504' image='C011' name='C# in Depth'/>
                  <book id='20505' image='C02' name='ASP.NET 2.0'/>
                  <book id='20506' image='C03' name='LINQ in Action '/>
                  <book id='20508' image='C04' name='Architecting Applications'/>
                </Books>";

XDocument xml1 = XDocument.Parse(s1);
XDocument xml2 = XDocument.Parse(s2);

//get cartesian product (i think)
var result1 =   from xmlBooks1 in xml1.Descendants("book")
                from xmlBooks2 in xml2.Descendants("book")
                select new { 
                            book1 = new {
                                        id=xmlBooks1.Attribute("id").Value,
                                        image=xmlBooks1.Attribute("image").Value,
                                        name=xmlBooks1.Attribute("name").Value
                                      }, 
                            book2 = new {
                                        id=xmlBooks2.Attribute("id").Value,
                                        image=xmlBooks2.Attribute("image").Value,
                                        name=xmlBooks2.Attribute("name").Value
                                      } 
                             };

//get every record that has at least one attribute the same, but not all
var result2 = from i in result1
                 where (i.book1.id == i.book2.id 
                        || i.book1.image == i.book2.image 
                        || i.book1.name == i.book2.name) &&
                        !(i.book1.id == i.book2.id 
                        && i.book1.image == i.book2.image 
                        && i.book1.name == i.book2.name) 
                 select i;



foreach (var aa in result2)
{
    //you do the output :D
}
```

Both linq statements probably could be merged, but I leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: I would be surprised if this actually works like requested Do you really want a cross join (cartesian product)?

Comment: Yea it works. Next time you can check it yourself, before commenting. Now lets 'review' your solution.

Comment: It produces the same result for this example set, yes. But it does not solve the general problem as I understand  it. For example, suppose xml2's book with id=20508 was a typo and the next entry had the 'real' 20508 data in each source. Your solution would return two rows; mine would return one. Both correct answers depending on the question.

Comment: Hi Grega 
What about If we have a book which is missing first xml or second xml, which lines I have to add in above code to work.

Comment: You mean if one book is only in one xml and not in the other? What do you want to happen than?

Answer (score 2):

For fun, a general solution to grega g's reading of the problem. To illustrate my objection to this approach, I've introduced a  "correct" entry for 'PowerShell in Action'.

```
string s1 = @"<Books>
     <book id='20504' image='C01' name='C# in Depth'/>
     <book id='20505' image='C02' name='ASP.NET'/>
     <book id='20506' image='C03' name='LINQ in Action '/>
     <book id='20507' image='C04' name='Architecting Applications'/>
     <book id='20508' image='C05' name='PowerShell in Action'/>
    </Books>";
string s2 = @"<Books>
     <book id='20504' image='C011' name='C# in Depth'/>
     <book id='20505' image='C02' name='ASP.NET 2.0'/>
     <book id='20506' image='C03' name='LINQ in Action '/>
     <book id='20508' image='C04' name='Architecting Applications'/>
     <book id='20508' image='C05' name='PowerShell in Action'/>
    </Books>";

XDocument xml1 = XDocument.Parse(s1);
XDocument xml2 = XDocument.Parse(s2);

var res = from b1 in xml1.Descendants("book")
          from b2 in xml2.Descendants("book")
          let issues = from a1 in b1.Attributes()
                       join a2 in b2.Attributes()
                         on a1.Name equals a2.Name
                       select new
                       {
                           Name = a1.Name,
                           Value1 = a1.Value,
                           Value2 = a2.Value
                       }
          where issues.Any(i => i.Value1 == i.Value2)
          from issue in issues
          where issue.Value1 != issue.Value2
          select issue;
```

Which reports the following:

```
{ Name = image, Value1 = C01, Value2 = C011 }
{ Name = name, Value1 = ASP.NET, Value2 = ASP.NET 2.0 }
{ Name = id, Value1 = 20507, Value2 = 20508 }
{ Name = image, Value1 = C05, Value2 = C04 }
{ Name = name, Value1 = PowerShell in Action, Value2 = Architecting Applications }
```

Note that the last two entries are the "conflict" between the 20508 typo and the otherwise correct 20508 entry.

Comment: @grega g  how to spot the differences in the attribute values when there are 50 value pairs, do we need to compare by attribute name for each one or is there a better way to do the same. Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

The operation you want here is a Zip to pair up corresponding elements in your two sequences of books. That operator is being [added in .NET 4.0](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/11/03/c-4-0-feature-focus-part-3-intermezzo-linq-s-new-zip-operator.aspx), but we can fake it by using Select to grab the books' indices and joining on that:

```
var res = from b1 in xml1.Descendants("book")
                         .Select((b, i) => new { b, i })
          join b2 in xml2.Descendants("book")
                         .Select((b, i) => new { b, i })
            on b1.i equals b2.i
```

We'll then use a second join to compare the values of attributes by name. Note that this is an inner join; if you did want to include attributes missing from one or the other you would have to do quite a bit more work.

```
          select new
          {
              Row = b1.i,
              Diff = from a1 in b1.b.Attributes()
                     join a2 in b2.b.Attributes()
                       on a1.Name equals a2.Name
                     where a1.Value != a2.Value
                     select new
                     {
                         Name = a1.Name,
                         Value1 = a1.Value,
                         Value2 = a2.Value
                     }
          };
```

The result will be a nested collection:

```
foreach (var b in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Row {0}: ", b.Row);
    foreach (var d in b.Diff)
        Console.WriteLine(d);
}
```

Or to get multiple rows per book:

```
var report = from r in res
             from d in r.Diff
             select new { r.Row, Diff = d };

foreach (var d in report)
    Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Which reports the following:

```
{ Row = 0, Diff = { Name = image, Value1 = C01, Value2 = C011 } }
{ Row = 1, Diff = { Name = name, Value1 = ASP.NET, Value2 = ASP.NET 2.0 } }
{ Row = 3, Diff = { Name = id, Value1 = 20507, Value2 = 20508 } }
```

Comment: Well the thing with zip is that it joins first record from xml1 to first record of xml2. So if we mix xml1 a little - lets say we switch first and second <book> nodes - we get different result. That's why you need cross join. There is no reason to assume (from his question and comments) that only corresponding nodes should be compared.

Comment: The question was described as a diff. In a diff, order matters.