# Finding Matching Nodes in two XML files using linqpad and linq to xml is finding 0 results

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml, linqpad

I have two XML files with the same schema/structure but with different data. I am trying to use Linqpad (Linq to XML) to find the differences between the two files.

Here is my code...

```
XElement FILE1 = XElement.Load (@"..\FILE1.XML");
XElement FILE2 = XElement.Load (@"..\FILE2.XML");

var orders = from file1 in FILE1.Descendants("Players").Elements("Player")
                        select new {
                            name=new {
                                firstName=file1.Element("FirstName"),
                                lastName=file1.Element("LastName")
                            }                           
                        };

var orders2 = 
             from file2 in FILE2.Descendants("Players").Elements("Player")
                        select new {
                            name=new {
                                firstName=file2.Element("FirstName"),
                                lastName=file2.Element("LastName")
                            }                           
                        };

var matchingResults = from i in orders from j in orders2 where (i.name.firstName==j.name.firstName && i.name.lastName==j.name.lastName)
                            select i;
matchingResults.Dump()
```

The last Dump() is returning 0 results.  I KNOW there is matching data in the two files.

**EDIT** I forgot to mention that if I dump the results of each of the queries I get results (that are very similar) for both sequences.

I have also tried the approach shown here...
[Compare two xml and print the difference using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470011/compare-two-xml-and-print-the-difference-using-linq)

(which combines the files into one sequence and then does the compare) but I am geting the same result...0 results.

That approach also seems to create a cartesian product on the first orders sequence.

All I want is to find matching or missing nodes from the files.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What does the xml structure look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `matchingResults` is doing a compare of `XElement` (reference equality) - not `string` (string contents).  `orders` and `orders2` are selecting `firstName` and `lastName` as `XElement`.  So, to get what you expect, either change `orders` and `orders2` to select `firstName` and `lastName` as

```
firstName = file1.Element("FirstName").Value
```

or compare them in `matchingResults` as

```
i.name.firstName.Value == j.name.firstName.Value
```

Here's a full example using the first option:

```
XElement FILE1 = XElement.Parse(
@"<Root>
    <Players>
        <Player><FirstName>Bob</FirstName><LastName>Smith</LastName></Player>
        <Player><FirstName>John</FirstName><LastName>Smith</LastName></Player>
    </Players>
</Root>");
    XElement FILE2 = XElement.Parse(
@"<Root>
    <Players>
        <Player><FirstName>Bob</FirstName><LastName>Smith</LastName></Player>
        <Player><FirstName>Mike</FirstName><LastName>Smith</LastName></Player>
    </Players>
</Root>");

var orders = from file1 in FILE1.Descendants("Players").Elements("Player")
                    select new {
                        name=new {
                            firstName=file1.Element("FirstName").Value,
                            lastName=file1.Element("LastName").Value
                        }
                    };

var orders2 = from file2 in FILE2.Descendants("Players").Elements("Player")
                    select new {
                        name=new {
                            firstName=file2.Element("FirstName").Value,
                            lastName=file2.Element("LastName").Value
                        }
                    };

//orders.Dump();
//orders2.Dump();

var matchingResults = from i in orders from j in orders2
                                where (i.name.firstName == j.name.firstName && i.name.lastName == j.name.lastName)
                                select i;
matchingResults.Dump();
```

Comment: Now, if you would like to help with a more interesting question that would be great.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20218821/how-do-you-use-linq-to-xml-to-find-matching-nodes-in-two-different-xml-files