# How do you use linq to xml to find matching nodes in two different xml files

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml, linqpad

I just asked another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203593/finding-matching-nodes-in-an-xml-file-using-linqpad-and-linq-to-xml) and the answer was spot on.

But that addressed what was essentially a syntax problem.  Now I need help with an actual resolution.

This is the same code from the previou question (fixed up and with stuff added).

```
XElement FILE1 = XElement.Load (@"..\FILE1.XML");
XElement FILE2 = XElement.Load (@"..\FILE2.XML");

var orders = from file1 in FILE1.Descendants("Players").Elements("Player")
                        select new {
                            name=new {
                                clientID=ulm.Element("ClientID").Value,
                                firstName=file1.Element("FirstName").Value,
                                lastName=file1.Element("LastName").Value
                            }                           
                        };

var orders2 = 
             from file2 in FILE2.Descendants("Players").Elements("Player")
                        select new {
                            name=new {
                                clientID=ulm.Element("ClientID").Value,
                                firstName=file2.Element("FirstName").Value,
                                lastName=file2.Element("LastName").Value
                            }                           
                        };

var matchingResults = from i in orders from j in orders2 where (i.name.firstName==j.name.firstName && i.name.lastName==j.name.lastName)
                            select i;
matchingResults.Dump()
```

To make it interesting I have added a ClientID to each sequence result before trying to match them up.

What I need is to know does a Player node from order EXISTS in a player node from orders2.  Or does it NOT EXIST?  Ideally I would also be able to CHOOSE the selection criteria for the NOT EXISTS/EXISTS check.  (LastName, or FirstName && LastName, or ClientID only, etc.)

I have NO IDEA how to go about this.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: if you want the entire 'Player' node to match, try [DeepEquals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.deepequals(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

- Use [`Enumerable.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- Use concrete types instead of anonymous types.
- To be able to choose the selection criteria you can create a parameterized `IEqualityComparer<Client>`.

  ```
  class Client
  {
      public string ClientID { get; set; }
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }
  }

  [Flags]
  enum Criteria { 
      ClientID, FirstName, LastName
  }

  class ClientEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Client> {

      private Criteria criteria;
      public ClientEqualityComparer(Criteria criteria) {
          this.criteria = criteria;
      }

      #region IEqualityComparer<Client> Membres

      public bool Equals(Client x, Client y)
      {
          if (criteria.HasFlag(Criteria.ClientID) && x.ClientID != y.ClientID)
              return false;
          if (criteria.HasFlag(Criteria.FirstName) && x.FirstName != y.FirstName)
              return false;
          if (criteria.HasFlag(Criteria.LastName) && x.LastName != y.LastName)
              return false;
          return true;
      }

      public int GetHashCode(Client obj)
      {
          int hash = 17;
          if (criteria.HasFlag(Criteria.ClientID))
              hash = hash * 31 + obj.ClientID;
          if (criteria.HasFlag(Criteria.FirstName))
              hash = hash * 31 + obj.FirstName;
          if (criteria.HasFlag(Criteria.LastName))
              hash = hash * 31 + obj.LastName;
      }

      #endregion
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {

      IEnumerable<Client> orders;
      IEnumerable<Client> orders2;
      //...
      var matchingIdFn = orders.Intersect(orders2, 
          new ClientEqualityComparer(Criteria.ClientID | Criteria.FirstName));

      var matchingIdFnLn = orders.Intersect(orders2, 
          new ClientEqualityComparer(Criteria.ClientID | Criteria.FirstName | Criteria.LastName));

      var different = orders.Except(orders2, new ClientEqualityComparer(Criteria.ClientID | Criteria.FirstName));            
  }
  ```

---

```
var orders = from file1 in FILE1.Descendants("Players").Elements("Player")
                    select new Client{
                        ClientID=ulm.Element("ClientID").Value,
                        FirstName=file1.Element("FirstName").Value,
                        LastName=file1.Element("LastName").Value                        
                    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I second Ahmed KRAIEM's suggestion to use `Intersect` or `Except`

Here's another solution that lets you compare using any arbitrary lambda:

```
void Main()
{
XElement FILE1 = XElement.Parse(
@"<Root>
    <Players>
        <Player><ClientId>1</ClientId><FirstName>Bob</FirstName><LastName>Smith</LastName></Player>
        <Player><ClientId>2</ClientId><FirstName>John</FirstName><LastName>Smith</LastName></Player>
    </Players>
</Root>");
    XElement FILE2 = XElement.Parse(
@"<Root>
    <Players>
        <Player><ClientId>2</ClientId><FirstName>Bob</FirstName><LastName>Smith</LastName></Player>
        <Player><ClientId>3</ClientId><FirstName>Mike</FirstName><LastName>Smith</LastName></Player>
    </Players>
</Root>");

var orders = from file1 in FILE1.Descendants("Players").Elements("Player")
                    select new Player(Int32.Parse(file1.Element("ClientId").Value), file1.Element("FirstName").Value, file1.Element("LastName").Value);

var orders2 = from file2 in FILE2.Descendants("Players").Elements("Player")
                    select new Player(Int32.Parse(file2.Element("ClientId").Value), file2.Element("FirstName").Value, file2.Element("LastName").Value);

//orders.Dump();
//orders2.Dump();

var exists = orders2.Intersect(orders, new LambdaEqualityComparer<Player>((i, j) => i.FirstName == j.FirstName && i.LastName == j.LastName));
// or
//var exists = orders2.Intersect(orders, new LambdaEqualityComparer<Player>((i, j) => i.ClientId == j.ClientId));
exists.Dump();

var notExists = orders2.Except(orders, new LambdaEqualityComparer<Player>((i, j) => i.FirstName == j.FirstName && i.LastName == j.LastName));
// or
//var notExists = orders2.Except(orders, new LambdaEqualityComparer<Player>((i, j) => i.ClientId == j.ClientId));
notExists.Dump();
}

public class Player
{
public int ClientId { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }

public Player(int clientId, string firstName, string lastName)
{
    ClientId = clientId;
    FirstName = firstName;
    LastName = lastName;
}
}

public class LambdaEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
private Func<T, T, bool> EqualityComparer { get; set; }

public LambdaEqualityComparer(Func<T, T, bool> equalityComparer)
{
    EqualityComparer = equalityComparer;
}

public bool Equals(T x, T y)
{
    return EqualityComparer(x, y);
}

public int GetHashCode(T obj)
{
    // If the hash codes are different, then Equals never gets called. Make sure Equals is always called by making sure the hash codes are always the same.
    // (Underneath, the .NET code is using a set and the not (!) of a Find method to determine if the set doesn't already contain the item and should be added.
    // Find is not bothering to call Equals unless it finds a hash code that matches.)
    //return obj.GetHashCode();
    return 0;
}
}
```

Note that if you don't want to create a `Player` object, you can remove it completely, populate your anonymous objects in `orders` and `orders2` just like you were doing before, and create a `new LambdaEqualityComparer<dynamic>` instead of `new LambdaEqualityComparer<Player>`, though it will be slower due to reflection calls on dynamic.