# Compare Tree Views in C#

Tags: c#

I have two Tree views populated from XML files. I have them loaded side by side in the windows form.

`treeView1` and `treeView2`. I need to compare these two treeviews and highlight any difference in any of the nodes.

```
**treeView1**
BIOS_DETAILS
   -Manufacturer
        -- Hewlett Packard
   -Name
        -- Default System BIOS
   -Primary BIOS
        -- True

**treeView2**
BIOS_DETAILS
   -Manufacturer
        -- Hewlett Packard
   -Name
        -- Default System BIOS
   -Primary BIOS
        -- FALSE
```

I need to compare both these and highlight the differences in color. How is that done?

Comment: using XML to LINQ you can compare both treeView XML files and find the difference, and add a property to hold the highlited one's color / id

Comment: Checkout this answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1470523/1370442

Comment: Scratches head wondering why they would be different unless the files were different....

Comment: What platform are you working with? Winforms or WPF?

Comment: And what specifically are you stuck on? Is it the UI part of it or the logic to identify which nodes are different? How do you define differences? Does order matter?

Comment: Finally I have comeup with some code.+

Comment: Hi All,Thanks for your help.

I managed to come up with a solution to compare tree views and highlight the differences. Posting the code below.

Comment: void CompareTreeNodes(TreeView tv1, TreeView tv2) {
int tv1NodeCount=tv1.GetNodeCount(true);
int tv2NodeCount=tv2.GetNodeCount(true);
 if (tv1NodeCount != tv2NodeCount)
{
MessageBox.Show("Tree-1 and Tree-2 are not balanced. Comparison may not be realistic."+Environment.NewLine+
"Please check if the XMLs imported are for same type","Warning!",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}


int compare = Math.Min(tv1.Nodes.Count, tv2.Nodes.Count);
for (int i = 0; i < compare; i++)
{
CompareRecursiveTree(tv1.Nodes[i], tv2.Nodes[i]);
}}
    }